# JQuery UI Sortable: Save keys with sort order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, sorting

I am using this code to save my JQuery UI sort order:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sortable').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/sort.php'
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

This produces an array of numbers. Let's say I also want to save keys with the numbers, based on tags in my list items.

So for example a sorted list such as:

```
<ul id='sortable'>
<li id='item-3' name='special'><image src='special.jpg'></li>
<li id='item-1' name='normal'><image src='normal.jpg'></li>
<li id='item-2' name='extraordinary'><image src='extraordinary.jpg'></li>
</ul>
```

Would produce this array in PHP:

```
$item['special'] = 3;
$item['normal'] = 1;
$item['extraordinary'] = 2;
```

I know how to access the tags with JQuery but not how to serialize these into an array to pass to my PHP script along with the sorted numbers. Help!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, dfsq! I also found toArray, which works if you only need the keys.

```
$(function() {
    $('#sortable').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'data-name'});
        //alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            data: {data:data},
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php'
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct data object manually with keys as name attribute and value index of the element (plus 1, it's zero-based):

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = {};
        $('#sortable').children().each(function() {
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).index() + 1;
        });
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/sort.php'
        });
    }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

Then on the server you will have POST array like `$_POST['normal'] = 1`, etc.

Alternatively you could pass items as part of items "nested" array:

```
data['item[' + $(this).attr('name') + ']'] = $(this).index() + 1;
```

and have POST array like `$_POST['item']['normal'] = 1`.